# Replaced the cable. Now the screen doesn't work. What could it be?

Tags: hardware, thunderbolt, thunderbolt-display

The cable that comes out of the back of my Apple Thunderbolt Display was fraying. I decided that rather than risk a short at some point, I'd preemptively replace the cable. Upon iFixit teardown photos, I decided to replace the cable that comes out of the back of the screen myself instead of paying nearly $200 to get an Apple Service Provider to do it here in Bangkok. Bought the cable on AliExpress for $12. Replaced it. And ... no dice. Screen did not come on.

**My setup**

```
[MacBook Air] ---- [Thunderbolt Display] --- [Thunderbolt drive] --- [Cinema Display]
```

*with a USB drive and Ethernet plugged into the back of the Thunderbolt Display*

**Already tried**

- Initial thoughts were that the cable was faulty. But then I noticed
  Ethernet came on, the USB drive was mounted, Thunderbolt drive was
  mounted and after a reboot the Cinema Display also come on.
  Obviously, the cable was working just fine.
- Second thought was that I had neglected to reconnect some cables that connect the LCD panel to the main logic board. I checked. Seemed just fine.
- Third was that
  perhaps the cable serial number was somehow tied to the main logic
  board. So I put the old cable back. Still no screen.
- Tried to
  connect the screen using an external Thunderbolt cable, everything
  worked equally well but still no image on the screen.
- Tried 30+
  seconds and 3+ hours unplugged as a 'reset' of the screen. No change.
- Rebooted my laptop. No change.
- Plugged the Thunderbolt Display into
  the drive and then into the MacBook, so change the sequence of
  devices. No change.
- System Information reports under "Thunderbolt"
  the whole chain of devices, but under "Graphics/Displays" shows only
  the internal screen and Cinema Display.
- Using the newly-purchased
  cable as an external Thunderbolt cable works just fine too.

**Question**

Does anybody have any suggestions on what to try next?

Does the logic board go into some kind of lockdown mode when replacing the cable?
Are there more than 3 connecting flat cables + ground connection between the panel and the main logic board?
Although there is no reason to assume it has been, how do I test the LCD panel to still function given all these flat cable connectors?

*Note: There are no Apple Stores here.  Apple Authorised Service providers are no help. They suggested replacing the cable and the panel at a cost that is nearly the same as buying a new screen.*

Comment: Do the USB ports on the TB Display work?  Just curious.  It seems that everything is working except the display portion of the TB Display.  You could have damaged something in removal and/or shorted something out if you didn't **disconnect** the power supply from the logic board prior to disassembly **then press the power button** to dissipate any remaining charge held the capacitors?

Comment: Correct, only the display portion isn't working. USB ports are working fine. I did disconnect the power supply, but to remove the LCD panel before I could do that. This involved unplugging 3 'flat cables' and a ground connection. There is no power button on the screen though.

Comment: Did you damage the LVDS cable/connector going from the display to the logic board?  This is a common occurrence.  Are both ends connected securely?  There should also be two connectors from the display to the logic board - one for power and the other for signal.  Are **both** connected/

Comment: There are 3 connectors plus a ground connection. One on the back side of he logic board which looks a bit tougher and has only a dozen or so contacts. One very fragile looking one with many contacts from the looks of it on the panel side of the logic board, which has a little lip attached to pull out the connector. This one is the shortest of all. And a small one with I think has 3 contacts. I can't see the panel end of these cables, as they disappear under tape. On the logic board end they *look* fine. Any way I can test the panel to still be working properly?

Comment: Additional: 
[1st mentioned] The one on the left in https://d3nevzfk7ii3be.cloudfront.net/igi/ePSBDAfyxGSod6f5.huge
[2nd mentioned] The one on the right (gold coloured) in https://d3nevzfk7ii3be.cloudfront.net/igi/ePSBDAfyxGSod6f5.huge
[3rd mentioned] The small socket just below the gold colored socket in https://d3nevzfk7ii3be.cloudfront.net/igi/VQSb2fPo6WJUvMwQ.huge

Comment: For the display itself, there are only two that matter, the third one is the iSight .  The gold one is your LVDS connector - what does it look like on the **display** end?  The only way to test this panel out is to hook it up to a to another display source.

Comment: I'll have to take it apart again in the morning. Took it out to an Apple service center today. Not enough light to work by at this hour. Appreciate your comments and help!

Comment: Hi Allan - so I took the screen apart again and I think the LVDS cable had indeed become undone on the panel side under the tape covering it. Undoing the tape might have done that, but I think it was already done. So I've put everything back and am now left with the logic board side of the LVDS cable.

Comment: Please see photos 3 and 4 on https://www.evernote.com/shard/s1/sh/d72d1816-20ab-4f8e-afda-7205ccbe10e4/0be7f867b3399e5f163cb4c00d066822 and you will see my sausage fingers holding the logic board side of the cable. I have tried but simply can't exert enough force to pull that black lip far enough for the metal brace to lock in over the board-side socket. That's needed to ensure the cable stays in, right? Or am I making stuff up now?

Comment: Yes!!!!!!! It worked. Allan, can you submit your suggestions as an answer so I can give you proper where it's due! And also .... how do I buy you a beer!?!! Thanks so much for your comments. I'm ecstatic!!

Comment: No worries...just added an answer...I am happy that you were able to get everything working!  Next time you are in the States (Miami) just give me a shout...I'll join you for that beer!

Comment: You're on. No plans right now, but one never knows. Equally, if you're in Bangkok or Singapore anytime, let me know! :-) Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all of your devices in the Thunderbolt "chain" are still functional including your Cinema display at the end of it all, chances are there is a problem with the connectors that go from the logic board in the Thunderbolt display to the display panel itself.

It's a quite common occurrence that when you disassemble this, that the connector comes loose.  Look to make sure that the LVDS and power connectors are securely attached at both the logic board side and on the display panel itself.